# goto function alternative and multiple printed lines in results

Tags: c#

Hoping someone can help. I'm still learning a lot each day as beginner. But have a few issues with the below.

1. The use of goto is a no-no from the research I have seen but I can't figure out an alternative loop to add while maybe? Or do?
2. When I enter text that I know will not return a result e.g. dsfgfhg and press enter I receive "Resource Not found " three times in the results. I assume this is because out of the list there are three entries and none match. How do I get one result instead of three when a resource is not found?
3. If I press enter twice in the console window without entering any text it returns everything in the list. Again I can't see a way to stop this. I guess I need to change the code to be explicit in some way?

Thanks again for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class JunkList
{
    public string Resource { get; set; }
    public string Junk { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public JunkList(string r, string j, int a)
    {
        this.Resource = r;
        this.Junk = j;
        this.Amount = a;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) // this is a method called "Main" . It is called when the program starts.
    {
        start: 
        string searchName;
        List<JunkList> infoList = new List<JunkList>();
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Type Writer", 2));
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Clip Board", 1));
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Toy Car", 3));
        Console.WriteLine("Which resource do you want to search for?? \n");
        searchName = Console.ReadLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < infoList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (infoList[i].Resource.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchName.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Resource : " + infoList[i].Resource + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Junk : " + infoList[i].Junk + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Resource Amount : " + infoList[i].Amount + "\n");

            } 
            else {

                 Console.WriteLine("Resource Not found <Press Enter to perform a new search>");
            } 
        }
        // wait for user to press a key. Then make an empty space and start over.
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine();
        goto start; // go to start and run again
    }
}
```

Comment: Infinite loops without any way out are frowned on  in general, but if you really want to go there, use a `while(true){`...`}` loop around everything. But a much better way is to make a boolean variable to check in the `while` loop, and use some specific value returned from the `ReadLine`, or the `ReadKey` at the end, to set that variable to False and abort the next loop.

Comment: You could use `while(true) { [your code] }` but you should consider adding an exit condition like `if (searchname == "") return;`

Comment: As for the rest... please don't ask multiple questions in one SO question; it makes it difficult to pinpoint "the" answer when people answer. But the general way to search is to loop over the list, indicate the result you found in a variable, and only evaluate that result _after_ the loop. Oh, and don't use `ToLower` for search; use case-insensitive search using `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead.

Comment: _"f I press enter [...] window without entering any text it returns everything in the list"_ you need to check if `searchName` ist not an empty string and only then seach for the desiered item.

Comment: The `String.Contains` is a substring search. An empty string will always be a valid substring of any given string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use 'single responsibility principle'. In your case that means that you should split your `Main` method into smaller methods. These methods do one simple action, i.e. responsibility.

Well, it will help:

1. You are right `goto` quite often is a bad practice (but not always). Put your code into `while(true)` and it would do the same but more clear. However, to close your application correctly receiving some char or key to exit would be better, e.g.

   ```
   bool _runApplication = true;
   while (_runApplication)
   {
       // code between "start:" and "goto start;"

       if (Console.Read() == 'x')
       {
           _runApplication = false;
       }
   }
   ```
2. To solve this multiple `Resource Not found` output you can separate searching by name and printing searching results, e.g.

   ```
           string searchName = Console.ReadLine();
           List<JunkList> searchResult = GetJunkListsBySearchName(infoList, searchName);

           if (searchResult.Count != 0)
           {
               foreach (var junkList in searchResult)
               { 
                   Console.WriteLine("Resource : " + junkList.Resource + "\n");
                   Console.WriteLine("Junk : " + junkList.Junk + "\n");
                   Console.WriteLine("Resource Amount : " + junkList.Amount + "\n");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Resource Not found <Press Enter to perform a new search>");
           }
   ```

where new method is:

```
    private static List<JunkList> GetJunkListsBySearchName(List<JunkList> infoList, string searchName)
    {
        List<JunkList> output = new List<JunkList>();

        foreach (var junkList in infoList)
        {
            if (junkList.Resource.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchName.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                output.Add(junkList);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

3. It is because of `searchName` is equal to en empty string. Add a simple `if` to solve it.

   ```
           if (searchName.Length > 0 &&
               junkList.Resource.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchName.ToLowerInvariant()))
           {
               output.Add(junkList);
           }
   ```

Applying all these points you will get code like this (only `Program` class modified):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool _runApplication = true;

        while (_runApplication)
        {
            List<JunkList> infoList = CreateJunkList();
            Console.WriteLine("Which resource do you want to search for?? \n");

            string searchName = Console.ReadLine();
            List<JunkList> searchResult = GetJunkListsBySearchName(infoList, searchName);

            if (searchResult.Count != 0)
            {
                PrintJunkLists(searchResult);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Resource Not found <Press Enter to perform a new search>");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (Console.Read() == 'x')
            {
                _runApplication = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<JunkList> CreateJunkList()
    {
        List<JunkList> infoList = new List<JunkList>();
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Type Writer", 2));
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Clip Board", 1));
        infoList.Add(new JunkList("Screw", "Toy Car", 3));

        return infoList;
    }

    private static void PrintJunkLists(List<JunkList> junkLists)
    {
        foreach (var junkList in junkLists)
        {
            PrintJunkList(junkList);
        }
    }

    private static void PrintJunkList(JunkList junkList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Resource : " + junkList.Resource + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Junk : " + junkList.Junk + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Resource Amount : " + junkList.Amount + "\n");
    }

    private static List<JunkList> GetJunkListsBySearchName(List<JunkList> infoList, string searchName)
    {
        List<JunkList> output = new List<JunkList>();

        foreach (var junkList in infoList)
        {
            if (searchName.Length > 0 &&
                junkList.Resource.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchName.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                output.Add(junkList);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

I hope it helped)

Comment: This was a brilliant answer and very detailed. Thank you for taking the timeout to be thorough and explain everything.

Comment: Hi I tested the code and it does work nearly as I expected however if you press enter twice for example or after the first search it displays:     Which resource do you want to search for??

Resource Not found <Press Enter to perform a new search>  I'm unsure where in the code it is causing this.

Comment: Oh, yeah, because of `if (Console.Read() == 'x')` code works a bit weird. Replacing it with `if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'x')` should help.